# How to make display name bigger in sharepoint power shell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am running the sharepoint 2010 Management Shell and I am did this

```
Get-SPFeature –Site http://sp2010
```

Comes back with

```
DisplayName             Id           Scope
--------------------------------------------
TheOneIWantIsToLo.... someId         Site
```

Now I need the display name to deactive the feature and active again. Yet I don't know what the full name is as it cuts it off.

How can I make it bigger so it won't do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

`Get-SPFeature -Site http://sp2010 | format-table -auto`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the display name you can also use:

```
Get-SPFeature –Site http://sp2010 | ForEach-Object {write-host $_.DisplayName}
```